# UITableView scrolls up twice when tapping UITextField followed by a UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uidatepicker

I have a `UITextField` and a `UIDatePicker` in my `UITableView`.

When I tap my textField, the table scrolls up to accomodate the keyboard showing up.

But tapping the label that calls the datePicker (While the keyboard's open) makes the picker view replace the keyboard (as intended) but the entire table scrolls up another notch. (Not so intended)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the same problem before. I fixed it by creating a delay to scroll the tableview:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(delaysetContentOffset:) withObject:[NSNumbernumberWithFloat:distance2KeyBoard] afterDelay:0.2];

- (void)delaysetContentOffset:(NSNumber *)offset
{
    [_scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, [offset floatValue]) animated:YES];
}
```

Hope this can help you too.